# implementing Flyway in an existing project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, flyway

I inherited a project that uses Spring Boot, Hibernate and PostgreSQL. I am coming to the close of version 2.0 and have made significant changes to the database. I have a script that works off of the production db (a snapshot), renames the schema and one table. Then when I next run my Java code, Hibernate updates the existing tables (new columns) and adds several new tables. Two more SQL scripts fill in the new columns, and fill in new tables that were created to hold data that was previously stored in hard coded Java constants.

So far it all hangs together well, but I want to implement Flyway to automate my database updates. However, all of the blogs, etc. that I have found to date talk about implementing Flyway in a scratch project, not adding it to an existing project.

So far, I have gotten Flayway "working" - my project will start and run without spewing errors. Here is my Flyway config from applcationContext.xml:

```
  <!-- Flyway db migration -->
  <bean id="flywayConfiguration" class="org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration" depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="schemas">
      <array>
        <value>"radar2"</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="true"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
   <constructor-arg ref="flywayConfiguration"/>
 </bean>
```

And I have built a set up migration scripts, in the default location (`resources\db\migration`)

Note, that I have turned off Hibernate's Validate and Update options, so it is no longer automatically updating my DB.

### So my question:

My migration scripts are not running. **What have I missed?**

I know that the migrations are not running because when I look at the flyway_schema_history table it only has the baseline entry, and the tables in my V2_0 script have not been created.

`V2_0_create_tables.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE radar2."comment" (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  photo_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  short_desc varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  machine_id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT comment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE radar2."comment" ADD CONSTRAINT fk4vjadovig0ru9qinlq9ov9jd8 FOREIGN KEY (machine_id) REFERENCES radar2.machine(id);

CREATE TABLE radar2.customer (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  uri varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  country_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  email_group varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

## UPDATE

I tried @Jens' suggestion (deleted after I commented that it did not help) and un-commented `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>` so that it is not being processed again and that changes my output:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\bin\javaw.exe -server -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=12288 -Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true -classpath C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\.adf;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\bin;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang3-3.6.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool2-2.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-text-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpmime-4.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\javax.mail-1.5.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jbcrypt-0.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jjwt-0.9.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-api-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-core-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\opencsv-4.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\postgresql-9.4.1211.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\smartsheet-sdk-java-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-support-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-expression-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jcl-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-config-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-jdbc-9.0.6.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-juli-9.0.6.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections4-4.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-compress-1.19.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\flyway-core-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\flyway-core-6.1.0.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\tullych\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore5440372196483254699.jks com.bh.radar.util.UtilAddUser
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 12288
Debugger connected to local process.
Dec 16, 2019 12:57:47 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4dfa3a9d: startup date [Mon Dec 16 12:57:47 EST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 16, 2019 12:57:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Dec 16, 2019 12:57:49 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Dec 16, 2019 12:57:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Exception breakpoint: AbstractApplicationContext.java:576, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed
```

Googling for `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` most commonly turns up database errors. However, if I comment out the Flyway code in applicationContext.xml and un-comment the `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>` l,ine, then Hibernate will update my schema.

### So, I am still puzzled...

## New UPDATE

Out of frustration, I deleted all trace of Flyway from my project, and tested it once more that way and have verified that it still works. YAY! :)

Now, back to the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup). According to them, I should be able to:

> To automatically run Flyway database migrations on startup, add the org.flywaydb:flyway-core to your classpath.

So, I added the Maven dependency back into my pom.xml file, and in Oracle J Developer, opened the Project Properties dialog. Then on the Libraries and Classpath tab I clicked Add Jar/Directory and navigated to the `flyway-core-6.1.2.jar` file that Maven downloaded for me.

After doing a Maven Clean-Package to clear out the old binaries and rebuild everything, I get no compilation or build errors. However, when I run my project in the debugger, I get the following:

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\bin\javaw.exe -server -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=14687 -Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true -classpath C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\.adf;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\bin;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool2-2.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-text-1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpmime-4.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\javax.mail-1.5.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jbcrypt-0.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\jjwt-0.9.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-api-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-core-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\opencsv-4.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\postgresql-9.4.1211.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\smartsheet-sdk-java-2.2.5.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-context-support-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-expression-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jcl-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-config-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-jdbc-9.0.6.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-juli-9.0.6.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections4-4.4.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-compress-1.19.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Users\tullych\dev\java\bh\radar-backend-add-flex\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\flyway-core-6.1.2.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Users\tullych\AppData\Local\Temp\trustStore5440372196483254699.jks com.bh.radar.util.UtilAddUser
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 14687
Debugger connected to local process.
Dec 17, 2019 4:38:03 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4dfa3a9d: startup date [Tue Dec 17 16:38:03 EST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 17, 2019 4:38:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]
Dec 17, 2019 4:38:04 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Dec 17, 2019 4:38:06 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Exception breakpoint: AbstractApplicationContext.java:576, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException, Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed
```

Is this a version compatibility issue? I see nothing in the Spring Docs about specific versions of Flyway.

I have made no mention of flyway in my applicationContext.xml file at this point, just added the dependency to pom.xml.

When I Google `nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` most of the hits focus on inability to connect to the database, but I have verified that I have a working database connection above and just added the bare minimum of flyway to my project and I am getting this error. I am I missing some configuration step?

Comment: Spring Boot has auto-configuration for Flyway, which makes sure it runs at the right time, etc.. Why are you using XML with Spring Boot, and reinventing the wheel? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool

Comment: I'm using XML configuration for this project, because that is how it was setup when I inherited it. As for "reinventing the wheel" if I am doing so, that is because I am still trying to wrap my head around Flyway. I will reread the docs you linked. And I see lots of confusion because most blogs today use annotations instead of XML configuration for Spring.

Comment: Further complication for me is that the Spring docs linked by @JB Nizet assume Java based configuration and I inherited XML configuration.